# Spring cloud zuul: How to use 2 different apache HTTP client implementations

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-httpclient-4.x, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

We customized the default zuul apache http client by providing our own `CloseableHttpClient` bean like this.

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws Throwable {
    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier((hostName, sslSession) -> true)
            .useSystemProperties()
            .build();
}
```

Now, we need to use 2 different apache http client implementations with different cert details. How can this be done?

This is because in the Zuul filter, depending on some checks we set `context.setRouteHost(serverUrl);` to one of the 2 values. So if its server1, we need to use a different certificate configurations vs if its server2.

Comment: That's not currently possible. You'd have to write a custom `route` filter.

Comment: @spencergibb How can I do that? Even if i create a different filter zuul still uses only one apache client bean right?

Comment: Your filter would have to create separate clients and not use the one provided by spring cloud.

Comment: @spencergibb Do u have any link to any doc that I can refer? Couldnt find anything here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html